# $P_1 \vee P_2 $ , $Q_1 \vee Q_2 $ are semi-decidable predicates and $P_2 = \overline{Q_2}$. What can be said about $P_1 \vee Q_1 $?

Tags: predicate-logic, computability

We've just started studying the decidability notion in our Algorithms class. So far we've only defined it and went through some examples of problems that fit different cases : decidable, semi-decidable, undecidable. But that's it. On our test today, this question popped up:

---

Consider the predicates $P_1,P_2,Q_1,Q_2 : R$ $\rightarrow \{0,1\}$ such that $P_1 \vee P_2 $ , $Q_1 \vee Q_2 $ are semi-decidable and $P_2 = \overline{Q_2}$. What can be said about $P_1 \vee Q_1 $?

---

I looked on the web before coming here, but I don't really understand how to approach this kind of problems. Can anyone help?

Comment: If you consider $P_2$ as always $1$ and $Q_2=Q_1$ (as always $0$) then $P_1$ can be anything and you can't say anything. Are you sure about the question ?